# XAMPP update to PHP 5.4

Tags: php, xampp

Hi I'm using XAMPP with PHP Version 5.3.1, how can I update to PHP 5.4 alpha 1 version?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you are using Windows, but if you do, try [this](http://hype-free.blogspot.com/2007/07/updating-php-in-xampp-for-windows.html). Works for me, except that the DLLs were located in /apache/modules and not /apache/bin.

Remember to backup your old contents and to replace your php.ini! And, by the way: I downloaded my source files from here: http://windows.php.net/snapshots/

Comment: I found this guide more up-to-date  http://technoslab.blogspot.com/2012/03/upgrading-to-php-54-on-xampp.html

Comment: Now XAMPP has PHP 5.4.7 by dafault